# jqGrid 4.3.2 Failures

Tags: jqgrid, keyboard, editing, inline-editing

Trying this version of jqGrid out and experiencing problems.

1. ESC key is not programmed properly for Chrome and 'editRow' events. Major pain.
2. ENTER key does not save on editRow select elements with Firefox
3. setting a column to have editrules: required blows out with Javascript error missing isEmpty

Makes this version almost unusable.

Comment: What is your question? Could you provide test case for the first two problems? The second problem could probably be solved like I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10275708/315935). Which version from 4.3.2 you use (see UPDATED part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10302130/315935))

Answer (score 0):

Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditingTest.htm) where I made the fixes which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10275708/315935) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-4-3-2-bug-when-field-is-requried/#p26481). The problems which you described in your question can't reproduced on the demo.

Currently jqGrid has no automatic testing (like jQuery UI [use](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/tests) for example). So changes can produce new bugs. In the situation if the developer who uses jqGrid found a bug the user should  provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the bug. So if you next time get some problems you should provide the test case instead of the list of problems which you have.

Comment: I am sorry to report, but this demo clearly does continue to exhibit the failure. For example, if I set a row into inline editing mode, pressing ESC key does nothing in Chrome, but it does work in Firefox.

In a somewhat related manner, pressing the ENTER key on this demo in Firefox also fails to save the row. 

I am not sure what this demo is supposed to demonstrate in terms of a solution.

I would love to present a demo showing off the bugs I pointed out, but it appears I do not need to as the one Oleg is providing is serving that purpose.

Comment: The editRule has indeed been fixed for the Oleg Demo. That is good.
Clearly there is a misunderstanding here. The demo shows off the exact bugs in the exact browsers (although I might add I am using FF  11 and Chrome 18.

Comment: @DavidLazar: Sorry but I tested the demo (I mean [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditingTest.htm)) in IE9, Chrome 18, Firefox 12, Opera 11.62, Safari 5.1.5. All tests I did under Windows 7. I tested all one more time now. The test work in all browsers absolutely identical. No problems with Enter or Esc keys I could ever seen. Probably you use some Plugins in your browsers or some blocker which are the reason on the problems?

Comment: I will try the code again with virgin installs to validate. Thanks

Comment: Same problem. FF 11... NO PLUGINS. Demo fails. click on a row of the demo. select option in DD. Hit ENTER. Nothing happens. Safari worked perfect though.

Comment: @DavidLazar: Sorry, but I can can only repeat that I can't reproduce any problem. Moreover you get almost no information. What is "Demo fails"? Which error message you has. What happens? Can you debug the code with Firebug? In what place in the code of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` one is at the moment of error which values has the variables used? Such information could be helpful.

Comment: Ah yes! Turns out, there was a problem with a plugin on Chrome! Cheers!

Comment: There was NO ERROR being thrown by Javascript in any of these cases. It was intead a UX problem. If you hit ESC and nothing happens, or ENTER and nothing happens, you have to figure there is an event handler problem... anyway, removing vim plugin solved the issue.

Comment: @DavidLazar: Did removing of the plugin solved the problem in *both* Chrom and Firefox or you have still the problem in Firefox? Is the problem is solved now or not?

Comment: Removed the plugin from both, FF was still exhibiting issue, till I restarted it, then it functioned as expected. I will take away from this that the Keyboard events function fine, and your code fixes the isEmpty? issue.

Comment: @DavidLazar: Like I described in my answer the The modified version fixed both of the issues. If you downloads the file [jquery.jqGrid.src-this.js](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.2_/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-this.js) and compare it with the original [jquery.jqGrid.src.js](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.2_/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js) with respect of WinDiff.exe from Windows SDK for example you will see all lines which I changed.